# jQuery animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My code is as given below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#Layer1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:115px;
 z-index:1;
 left: 445px;
 top: 64px;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle()

{

$("#Layer1").animate({width:"20px"},1000);

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="toggle()">
<div id="Layer1"><img src="friend-line.jpg" width="243" height="380" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As the page loads, there is an animation, but soon enough, the dimensions of Layer 1 are restored. I'd like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The animation adds the CSS of `overflow:hidden` while it's going. When it stops, the `overflow` goes back to its previous state, so you should simply permanently add the `overflow:hidden` CSS to `#Layer1`

Additionally, I suggest that you use the jQuery doc ready functionality instead of the inline `onload` Javascript.

So your entire JS would be:

```
$(function() { // <== doc ready
    $("#Layer1").css("overflow","hidden").animate({width:"20px"},1000);
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6vyBF/)**

---

I'm not quite sure as to what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but you could also include the `overflow:hidden` in you CSS for `#Layer1`:

```
#Layer1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:115px;
 z-index:1;
 left: 445px;
 top: 64px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

With the above CSS you can use your original code, just wrap it in a doc ready and remove the `onload` from the HTML:

```
$(function() { // <== doc ready
    $("#Layer1").animate({width:"20px"},1000);
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BMTgK/)**

Note that the width of the div is smaller than the width of the image. Not sure if this is on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

its possibly because you are changing the `div` width and not the width of the `img`

also is best practice to use `$(document).ready()` on the script than using `onload` on `body`

if you do not wish to change the image size but just hide the reset of the contents on your css u can add `overflow: hidden;`

otherwise i cn't see why there should a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the dimensions of `Layer1` are not restored. However, the image size remains the same. The reason it's clipped during the animation is that the `animate` function automatically adds an `overflow: hidden;` declaration to whatever it's animating.

```
if ( opt.overflow != null ) {
    this.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
```

As soon as the animation stops, `overflow` is back to the default value which is `visible`. If you want it to remain clipped, just add an `overflow: hidden` declaration to your `#Layer1` CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

use percentage(%) in place of pixel(px) in your image width.
Because while you give image width in px , it retains the fixed width of the image.
And while you give it in percentage(%),The image's width divided by its parent element.
Your code should be like  following :

```
   <body onload="toggle()">
        <div id="Layer1"><img src="jquery-drag-drop/images/rrr.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
    </body>
```

[Click here to know more about jQuery animation with Images](http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/jquery-animation/)